# How to bind label for custom angularjs input?

Tags: css, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to know a simple way to bind label to custom angular input field.Current code doesn't work
Code is here

```
<div class="col-sm-3 padding-zero">
  <label for="past" class="lbl">Have You Ever Had Past History:</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9 padding-zero" >
  <tags-input ng-model="past_history"  placeholder="Past History" id="past" >
<auto-complete source="loadPast_history($query)" ></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
<input type="hidden" value="<% past_history %>" name="past_history" >
</div>
```

As I am not familiar with Angularjs,can anyone suggest a simple way to bind label for taginput field so that clicking on label focuses the taginput?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) to bind label to custom angular input field.